# Slack incoming webhook won't send @channel or @here. I'd like to notify everyone in a channel using a bot message

Tags: slack-api, slack-block-kit

HELP!!! I can't get <!channel> or <!here> to work using the Block Kit Builder. Would like to notify everyone in a channel when the bot sends a message.

[image of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOSLP.jpg)

Below is the code i'm using.

```html
{
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "header",
            "text": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "BUY/LONG",
                "emoji": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "{{ticker}} with 25% BP at  {{open}}",
                "emoji": true
            },
            "accessory": {
                "type": "button",
                "text": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "OPEN CHART",
                    "emoji": true
                },
                "value": "click_me_123",
                "url": "https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=kucoin%3AALGOUSDT",
                "action_id": "button-action"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "divider"
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "<!here>",
                "emoji": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: did you find a solution that worked?

Answer (score 1):

In the given code 'text type' must be ***"type": "mrkdwn"*** to make use of the 'mentions'.

```
   {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
            "type": "mrkdwn",
            "text": "<!here>",
            "emoji": true
        }
    }
```